# Mapbox / Leaflet / MarkerCluster - How to show multiple paths on the same coordinates

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, markerclusterer

On the map I'm working on, sometimes multiple markers will share the same coordinates. I'm using markercluster which is helpful to view markers that share the same coordinates. The problem is, that the paths(lines) that connect them fall on top of each other. I need to show both lines. Is it possible to have each line side by side or similar? Has anyone ran into this issue before? See the below image which shows what I am trying to accomplish.

[image: This image shows what I would like to accomplish for markers that fall on the same coordinates and are clustered]

Answer (score 1):

Try Leaflet Polyline Offset [plugin](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset). Here is [demo](http://bbecquet.github.io/Leaflet.PolylineOffset/examples/example_bus.html).